# Java KeyStroke.getKeyStroke modifier changed

Tags: java, awt

I have a question why the modifier of this KeyStroke changed from 128 to 130?

```
package de.roth.jsona.keyevent;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import com.sun.glass.events.KeyEvent;

public class KeyStrokeBug {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // getKeyStroke(KeyEvent, modifier)
        System.out.println(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

        // Prints out 128
        System.out.println(InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);
        KeyStroke k = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_0, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);

        // Prints out 130
        System.out.println(k.getModifiers());
    }
}
```

Comment: Same with 512 -> 520. It seems like it is up rounded to the next tenner.

Comment: Modifiers are bit OR'ed together, this allows them to carry multiple modifiers, such as [CTRL] and [ALT] and [SHIFT].  In order to detect these modifiers, you need to AND'd the modifier, for example `if ((e.getModifiers() & InputEvent.SHIFT_MASK) != 0)`. There's also the possibility that `InputEvent.CTRL_MASK` would be used instead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main cuplrit is in the `mapNewModifiers` method of `KeyStroke`...

```
private static int mapNewModifiers(int modifiers) {
    if ((modifiers & InputEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK) != 0) {
        modifiers |= InputEvent.SHIFT_MASK;
    }
    if ((modifiers & InputEvent.ALT_DOWN_MASK) != 0) {
        modifiers |= InputEvent.ALT_MASK;
    }
    if ((modifiers & InputEvent.ALT_GRAPH_DOWN_MASK) != 0) {
        modifiers |= InputEvent.ALT_GRAPH_MASK;
    }
    if ((modifiers & InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK) != 0) {
        modifiers |= InputEvent.CTRL_MASK;
    }
    if ((modifiers & InputEvent.META_DOWN_MASK) != 0) {
        modifiers |= InputEvent.META_MASK;
    }

    return modifiers;
}
```

Where it makes the `_DOWN_MASK`s to the older modifier `_MASK`s.  This is done for capability reasons...

For example...

```
InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK | InputEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK
```

Produces 192, where as...

```
InputEvent.CTRL_MASK | InputEvent.SHIFT_MASK
```

Produces 195, which is the value of the `getModifiers` value in both cases...

The final value is a result of a bitwise OR'ing process

If you have a look at the `_MASK` modifiers...

```
InputEvent.SHIFT_MASK
InputEvent.CTRL_MASK
InputEvent.ALT_MASK
InputEvent.META_MASK
InputEvent.ALT_GRAPH_MASK
```

These produce...

```
1
2
8
4
32
```

(Remember, there are mouse button masks as well) These are easily bit wised OR'd and AND'd into a single `int` value